# How to bind 64-bit and 32-bit executable into one?

Tags: windows, executable, 32bit-64bit, portable-executable, fat-binaries

Alright so my idea was some way to bind both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows executables into one application so if it doesn't run the 64-bit version it would then try the 32-bit one.

I was reading up about PE's and learned a little about MS-DOS Real Mode Stub and it says how it invokes an application (usually an error message). But every time I tried to do research about MS-DOS Real Mode Stub it seemed to only show error messages. So my idea was to overwrite the STUB with my 32-bit application.

My self being naive figured when the 32-bit operating system would run the the 64-bit executable it would fail and then run the stub file.

Is there any way to make my executable 32-bit/64-bit independent?

Comment: As an aside, the MS-DOS stub contains 16-bit instructions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could not create a single executable file, containing both `x86` and `x64` code. However you could create separate 32bit and 64bit applications, pack `x64` app into the `x86` app resources. On the program start you could check, that you are running `x64` environment using `IsWow64Process` then if needed, unpack your `x64` version and run it instead

Comment: AFAIK, this is what Microsoft’s own [SysInternals tools](http://sysinternals.com) do.

Answer (score 3):

There are [fat binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) in MacOS, Linux and DOS (or hybrid DOS-Windows) but not 32 and 64-bit Windows

You can simply compile separate versions of the program, distribute both and then **select the required version** at run time by a script or another executable

Another way is **installing only the desired version** at install time. This is used by many programs like CCleaner. The installer is a 32-bit app or a universal one like .NET so that it can run anywhere. If it detects 64-bit Windows then it only installs the 64-bit version, and in the other case only the 32-bit version.

Read more:

- [Universal binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary)
- [Windows 8 fat binary (exe for x86 & ARM)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7510225/995714)
- [Windows NT has always been a multi-platform OS, but the binaries are not](https://kurtraschke.com/2011/04/multi-platform-windows)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your time.