# How do certain Windows DLL apparently manage to support both 32 and 64 bit?

Tags: windows, dll, 32bit-64bit

I seem to be able to access the functions in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\opengl32.dll` (and likewise `C:\WINDOWS\system32\glu32.dll`) from either a 32-bit or a 64-bit application (for what it's worth, I'm doing this from separate 32-bit and 64-bit Python 2.7 interpreters, via the `ctypes` module).

With `glut32.dll`, things are different. It only happens to be on my `Path` as part of a 32-bit installation of GraphViz. From 32-bit Python, I can link dynamically to it, but from 64-bit Python I get `[Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

Now, this error does **not** surprise me, because I had always thought DLLs were obliged to commit to one architecture or another on Windows (in particular, [this recent question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759982/how-to-bind-64bit-and-32bit-executable-into-one) seem to say so).  What surprises me is the **lack** of an error in the first case... How does `opengl32.dll` do it, and how can I replicate this behaviour when building my own DLLs?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's just incredibly sneaky.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 64 bit system only 64 bit processes use `c:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll`. For 32 bit processes system redirects `c:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll` to `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll`.

[File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\lastgood\system32 is redirected to %windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\regedit.exe is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe.